Why is "Evil" capitalized in the Jubilee Prayer?
The 2025 Jubilee Prayer in English bothered my wife by capitalizing the word "Evil".

when, with the powers of Evil vanquished,
your glory will shine eternally.

https://www.usccb.org/prayers/jubilee-prayer
I really had no explanation for her and I've expended my bother the Bishops budget (because I was busy trying to get them to put a comma between "when" and "with") so I think it's worth asking here.  Is Evil personified in the person of Satan? Or is it the Gates of Hell or the name given to the collective forces of darkness?

to draw more emphasis on what that word implies, it implies a principality who is the source of evil.

Looking at it in other languages shows that some capitalize "evil" and some don't. Similarly some italicize "faith", "hope", and "charity", and some don't. These differences seem to be a choice of the individual translators.

"bothered my wife by capitalizing the word" — how about the italicized "faith", "hope", and "charity"? They bother me more than any other aspect of it. (Either one gets the connection or one doesn't, the italics seem tacky.)

@RayButterworth yeah, I noticed that, but I don't think I would have if it wasn't italicized - then again, it's a prayer, I don't think I needed to notice it.  It is not italicized on the promotional material outside of the USCCB's website.

And as far as other languages are concerned, I did see Mal capitalized on one version of it.

"It is not italicized on the promotional material outside of the USCCB's website." — I think this is the official Vatican web site, with versions in 20 languages.

OK - that's official; this was the version we had on a brochure at church: https://i.sstatic.net/GPoWCFlQ.jpg

Why is "Evil" capitalized in the Jubilee Prayer?
First of all, here follows the Jubilee Prayer in it’s entirety:

Father in heaven, may the faith you have given us in your son, Jesus Christ, our brother, and the flame of charity enkindled in our hearts by the Holy Spirit, reawaken in us the blessed hope for the coming of your Kingdom.
May your grace transform us into tireless cultivators of the seeds of the Gospel. May those seeds transform from within both humanity and the whole cosmos in the sure expectation of a new heaven and a new earth, when, with the powers of Evil vanquished, your glory will shine eternally.
May the grace of the Jubilee reawaken in us, Pilgrims of Hope, a yearning for the treasures of heaven.
May that same grace spread the joy and peace of our Redeemer throughout the earth. To you our God, eternally blessed, be glory and praise for ever. Amen.
The Jubilee Prayer

As you may have guessed Evil is capitalized as a personification Satan together with his kingdom of evil.
An interesting note is the fact that the theological virtues of faith hope charity are italicized. With these three virtues we will be able with the graces infused by the Holy Spirit, in our souls conquer all the assaults that Satan (Evil) can muster against us.
Satan has already vanquished, but we needed to remain strong in the life of grace aided with the Holy Trinity, dwelling within our souls.
This Jubilee Prayer is indeed quite profound!

Any comment about why the capitalization and italicization differ from language to language? (E.g. French has neither.)

@RayButterworth The French version uses  a far less stronger wording. The expressions employed in the French version use weaker idiomatic expressions.

You've included italics. Is the word Evil really in bold?
